# VBA select dropdown menu website

Tags: html, excel, vba, web, dropdown

I'm currently trying to write something in `vba` to access a website and get information from a table. So far I only managed to login and navigate to the table, but what I want to do now is to filter the table first, by selecting different options on a dropdown menu.

Heres my code:

```
Sub browse()
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    WebSite = "https://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/login"
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate WebSite
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        Set Element = .document.getElementsByName("kennung")
        Element.Item(0).Value = "myemail"
        Set Element = .document.getElementsByName("passwort")
        Element.Item(0).Value = "password"
        .document.forms(0).submit
        .navigate "https://www.kicktipp.de/los-bwlos/gesamtuebersicht"
        While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Element = .document.getElementById("tippspieltagVonIndex")
        Element.Item(0).Value = 4
        Element.FireEvent ("onchange")
        Application.SendKeys (Enter)


        End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get different error messages when trying to select the dropdown menu, depending on if I use `getElementById` or `getElementsbyName`.

Heres the HTML of that section:

```
<tr class="e">
<td class="nw">
<div><label for="tippspieltagVonIndex">Spieltage</label>
</div></td><td><b>von</b> 
<select name="tippspieltagVonIndex" id="tippspieltagVonIndex">
<option selected="selected" value="1">1. Spieltag</option>
<option value="2">2. Spieltag</option>
<option value="3">3. Spieltag</option>
<option value="4">4. Spieltag</option>
<option value="5">5. Spieltag</option>
<option value="6">Achtelfinale</option>
<option value="7">Viertelfinale</option>
<option value="8">Halbfinale</option>
```

Comment: where is `Element` defined ?

Answer (score 0):

### SelectedIndex property

Instead of `Element.Item(0).Value = 4`
Try: `Element.Item(0).selectedIndex = 4`

### Code that works on extended login site HTML

I am unable to log in, so I added the `Select` tag to the login site. Every option in the code below worked for me.

```
Sub browse()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim Element As Object

    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.kicktipp.de/info/profil/login"
        Do While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop

        'element copied from your question, pasted into the login site HTML
        Set Element = .document.getElementById("tippspieltagVonIndex")
        'any option below did change the select element
        Element.Value = 1 '1. Spieltag
        Element.Value = "2" '2. Spieltag
        Element.selectedIndex= 2 '3. Spieltag because 0-based array

        .Quit
    End With 'objIE
End Sub
```

Comment: hi Branislav, i tried that, but im getting error 91. any idea what might cause the problem? thanks for your time & effort!

Comment: @JohannesEngelhardt Hi. I have tested the Selection part of question and edited my answer. If you still get an error after navigating to the second url, try explicitly `Set Element = Nothing` and then `Set Element = .document.getElementById("tippspieltagVonIndex")`. Also, in your code note the not existing `ie` object on line `While ie.ReadyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend`, change to `objIE`.